# How can I get a pointer to a C function?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, pinvoke, function-pointers

Some C function (A) takes a function pointer as a parameter. It checks wheter this pointer points to a certain C function (B). So, I need to pass the pointer to B into A. 
I assumed I could accomplish this by something like the following:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyDelegate();

[DllImport("somelibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void B();
```

and then to get the address of the function:

```
var pointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new MyDelegate(B));
```

But apparently, the pointer that I get doesn’t point to B (since, by calling `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` with two different delegates wrapped around B I get different results). 
So, is there a way to get a pointer that would point directly to B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I *think* you are trying to do is get the address of an unmanaged function. What `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` does is return a pointer to a managed address for unmanaged code to call, which isn't what you are looking for.

If you need to get the address of a native function from a module, you should use native Win32 to do that, like using `GetProcAddress` on your library. So what you would do is use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) (or one of its variants) to get a handle to the module, pass that to [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) along with the name of the export you are looking for, "B" in your example, then use [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) to decrement your reference count to the module. GetProcAddress's return value gives you the pointer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I upvoted it and will accept it as an answer once I make sure it works.